# How to create a draggable toggle switch with 3 states?

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop

I want to make the switch in the following image interactive.

[This is how it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnxzo.png)

You should be able to drag the thumb inside the bar and it should stick to the three anchor points (three white dots

If the thumb changes its anchor point I also want to execute a function (function is not related to the problem, however the function will display some text. So everytime the thumb changes its anchor point another text will be displayed above).
Here is my code if it helps:
HTML

```
 <div class="offer-con">
   <div class="switch-bar">
     <div class="switch-slider"></div>
     <div class="dot"></div>
     <div class="dot"></div>
     <div class="dot"></div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

SCSS

```
$secondary: #286A75;
$linear: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(0,159,227,1) 0%, rgba(40,57,117,1) 100%);

.offer-con {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.switch-bar {
  display: flex;
  height: 45px;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 1000px;
  border-radius: 80px;
  margin: 16px;
  background: $secondary;
  box-shadow: inset 4px 4px 8px 4px rgba($color: #000000, $alpha: 0.25);
  justify-content: space-between;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  align-items: center;
}

.switch-slider {
  position: absolute;
  height: 45px;
  width: 25%;
  max-width: 300px;
  border-radius: 138px;
  background: $linear;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 8px 8px 12px 4px rgba($color: #000000, $alpha: 0.4);
}

.dot {
  background-color: #ededed;
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 48px;
}
```

I thought about just adding a simple drag and drop functionality. Hower then the user would be able to drag the thumb out of the bar.

I also tried to search after tutorials, but I have no clue how the whole thing i want to code is called, what makes it difficult.
So I would be very grateful if someone could tell me what this is called or if someone could send me a link to a tutorial.

I dont really need someone to code this for me (I dont want to abuse the overflow community as freelancers)
However if you like to do this you would make someone very happy ;)

Comment: Could you rephrase the question. If this is not a scroll bar, call it something other -- is it more like a progress bar? You write "the thumb inside the track" -- what is that and where should it be dragged to (along the bar or something else)?

Comment: @chrwahl I am sorry for the confusion. I also provided an image to show how it looks like. The thumb is the div with the linear gradient (switch-slider) and the thumb is the other div (switch-bar). So the track is the same as bar. I want some functionality that allows me to drag the thumb(switch-slider) along the bar(switch-bar). I hope my question is clearer now.

Comment: Ok, it is a Toggle Switch with three states?

Comment: @chrwahl Yes, but I would like, that the user is able to switch between the options with dragging the thumb, not just clicking.

Answer (score 0):

In this example I give the slider a state. On `mousedown` I set the current `clientX` value (mouse position). I use this value to calculate the distance (delta) between the current mouse position and the initial. If the distance is greater than (+/-)50 the state of the slider changes.

```js
var switchslider;

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e => {
  switchslider = document.querySelector('#offer .switch-slider');

  switchslider.state = {
    down: false,
    value: 1
  };

  switchslider.classList.add('state1');

  switchslider.addEventListener('mousedown', e => {
    // set the initial state
    e.target.state.clientx = e.clientX;
    e.target.state.down = true;
  });
});

document.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
  if (switchslider.state.down) {
    // calculate the distance between initial mouse and now
    let delta = e.clientX - switchslider.state.clientx;
    let move = 0;
    // test position
    if (delta > 50 && switchslider.state.value < 3) {
      move = 1;
    } else if (delta < -50 && switchslider.state.value > 1) {
      move = -1;
    }
    // the slide moves to a new state
    if (move != 0) {
      switchslider.state.value += move;
      switchslider.className = `switch-slider state${switchslider.state.value}`;
      delta = 0;
      switchslider.state.down = false;
    }
    // move the slider
    switchslider.style.marginLeft = `${delta}px`;
  }
});

document.addEventListener('mouseup', e => {
  // reset the slider state on mouse up
  if (switchslider.state && switchslider.state.down) {
    switchslider.state.down = false;
    switchslider.style.marginLeft = '0';
  }
});
```

```css
.offer-con {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.state1 {
  grid-column: 1;
}

.state2 {
  grid-column: 2;
}

.state3 {
  grid-column: 3;
}

.switch-bar {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 30% 30% 30%;
  column-gap: auto;
  height: 45px;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 1000px;
  border-radius: 80px;
  margin: 16px;
  background: #286A75;
  box-shadow: inset 4px 4px 8px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
  justify-content: space-between;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  align-items: center;
}

.switch-slider {
  grid-row: 1;
  height: 45px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 300px;
  border-radius: 138px;
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(0, 159, 227, 1) 0%, rgba(40, 57, 117, 1) 100%);
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 8px 8px 12px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
}

.dot {
  background-color: #ededed;
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  grid-row: 1;
}

.dot:nth-child(1) {
  justify-self: start;
  margin-left: 24px;
  grid-column: 1;
}

.dot:nth-child(2) {
  justify-self: center;
  grid-column: 2;
}

.dot:nth-child(3) {
  justify-self: end;
  margin-right: 24px;
  grid-column: 3;
}
```

```html
<div id="offer" class="offer-con">
  <div class="switch-bar">
    <div class="dot"></div>
    <div class="dot"></div>
    <div class="dot"></div>
    <div class="switch-slider"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```